# Getting a 400 Bad Request when it should be a custom exception in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, exception, bad-request

I have the following code:

```
    @GetMapping("/customer/{id}")
    fun getCustomer(@PathVariable id: UUID): ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Customer>> {
        val customer = customerService.getCustomer(id)

        if(customer.code == ResultCode.FETCH_FAILURE) throw IncorrectUUIDException("Invalid ID: $id")

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(
            ApiResponse(
                entity = customer.entity
            )
        )
    }
```

My IncorrectUUIDException is this:

```
class IncorrectUUIDException(message: String) : RuntimeException(message)
```

However, when I deliberately provide an incorrect UUID to Spring Boot through Postman, I get the following error back:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-05-31T07:53:08.856+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/api/customer/d43769b8-5afa-4e47-8104-d8f1e7cfe7fg"
}
```

When I go through breakpoints and provide the correct UUID, the request is passed through to the function, but as soon as I pass an incorrect one, the function does not even have it passed through.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible exceptions that can be thrown can throw:

1. If the UUID is not conform to the UUID standards, a `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` is thrown because Spring cannot map the path variable to an instance of the `UUID` class.
2. The UUID is conform the standards, but the requests results in a `FETCH_FAILURE`. In this case you throw a `IncorrectUUIDException`.

The problem is that `d43769b8-5afa-4e47-8104-d8f1e7cfe7fg` is not conform the UUID standards because the last character ('g') is not a hexadecimal one. So in this case, a `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` is thrown and it doesn't enter your code.

You can customize what kind of response you get by defining your own exception handler for this. For example:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
public ErrorResponse methodArgumentTypeMismatch(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) {
    return ErrorResponse.builder(ex, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage()).build();
}
```

If you really want it to enter your method so you can throw an entirely different exception, you can do the mapping to a `UUID` by yourself by defining the `id` parameter as a `String` and using `UUID.fromString()`. In this case, a `NumberFormatException` is thrown, so you could rethrow it as a `IncorrectUUIDException`:

```java
@GetMapping("/customer/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Customer>> getCustomer(@PathVariable String id) { // Use `String` in stead of `UUID`
    try {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(id); // Map the id by yourself
        // ...
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        throw new IncorrectUUIDException(ex); // Rethrow the `NumberFormatException` as an `IncorrectUUIDException`
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to leave it entirely up to your `customerService`, you could change your `getCustomer()` method so that it also accepts a `String` and pass the ID as a `String`.